# Meter servidor (Win 2012 Server R2) a un dominio como servidor miembro

Tags: windows, servidor

Tengo un servidor principal Active Directory que hace de servidor de dominio, y el otro lo tengo en la misma red y de uno al otro se encuentran, pero no puedo meter el segundo en dominio, me dice

> No se puede poner en contacto con un controlador de dominio Active
>   Directory en el dominio DOMINIO, asegurese que el nombre de dominio
>   esta escrito correctamente.

En mi caso el nombre de dominio esta escrito correctamente.

Las DNS están correctamente como todos los demás equipos del edificio pero no hay manera de conectar el servidor secundario.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a hacerlo con el comando Netdom?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788018(v=ws.11).aspx